# Jquery range slider with manual input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, jquery-1.8

Hi I have been using jQuery range slider which does not support touch devices. I have tried the touch punch but it didnt really made any difference

**I want to give the user the option to enter the value of the slider manually along with the scroll functionality.**

**I'm using jquery 1.8 and when I try to update it to the latest jquery there are some performance issues.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ for quite a few projects. It's designed to work for both desktop and touch devices..